# Chart.js - Adding tooltips to radar chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I want to add tooltips to the Radar chart in chart.js.

So I tried in 3 ways :

1st:

```
var options = Chart.defaults.global = {showToolTips:true};
new Chart(ctx).Radar(data,options);
```

2nd:

```
new Chart(ctx).Radar(data,{showTooltips:true);
```

3rd:

In this , I added the `showTooltips:true` to the global properties of the Radar chart in chart.min.js of my project.

Sadly , all three of them failed. And suprisingly , the first method doesn't even display the chart.
It gives the following error in the chrome console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'global' of undefined
```

I'm stuck .Please help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't tooltips shown by default in chart.js?

Check the sample provided in the library itself: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/radar.html

Comment: Yes , I got it. My project had an older version of chart.js which didn't support tooltips. I have now updated it. Thanks for your answer